# Escape json tags in bash script or jq

Tags: bash, shell, jq, yq

I have a YAML file which I am converting into JSON files using `yq`.
It generates the following output,

```
{
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : 2,
  "c" : {
  "id": "9ee ...",
  "parent": "abc..."
  }
}
```

Then I am creating another JSON based on the above JSON key & value. Please find the below code snippet,

```
# Extract the properties from the YAML file
json=$(yq -j "$file_name")

# Iterate over the properties
parameters=""
for key in $(echo "${json}" | jq -r 'keys[]'); do

    # Extract the key and value of the property
    value=$(echo "${json}" | jq -r ".$key")
    echo "Adding parameter $key with value $value to SSM"

    # Add the property to the list of parameters
    parameters+="{\"Name\": \"$key\", \"Value\": \"$value\", \"Type\": \"String\", \"Overwrite\": true}"
done
```

Since the value in the 1st JSON is already JSON so we couldn't able to generate the 2nd JSON which is generating an invalid-JSON error.

Is there any way to escape/stringify the JSON characters in `bash script` or `jq`, so that we can able to generate the 2nd JSON?

Any help would be really appreciated.

**Actual output:**

```
[
{
"Name": "a",
"Value": "1",
"Type": "String",
"Overwrite": "true"
},
{
"Name": "b",
"Value": "2",
"Type": "String",
"Overwrite": "true"
},
{
"Name": "c",
"Value": "{
      "id": "9ee ...",
      "parent": "abc..."
      }",
"Type": "String",
"Overwrite": "true"
}
]
```

The above one is not a valid JSON.

****Expected output:****

```
[
{
"Name": "a",
"Value": "1",
"Type": "String",
"Overwrite": "true"
},
{
"Name": "b",
"Value": "2",
"Type": "String",
"Overwrite": "true"
},
{
"Name": "c",
"Value": "{\r\n      \"id\": \"9ee ...\",\r\n      \"parent\": \"abc...\"\r\n      }",
"Type": "String",
"Overwrite": "true"
}
]
```

Comment: What do you want the final output to look like?

Comment: What's the output JSON you'd want based on that sample input? Especially, the value of `c` is not a string, it's another object (i.e. a dictionary), so how should it be handled? Also, the current code generates a sequence of objects; should they be in an array or something?

Comment: What is your final goal? If you're dealing with JSON all along, process everything with jq, and you won't have to worry about its encoding. Better yet, as for the conversion you seem to be using kislyuk/yq, which internally is just a wrapper around jq, so you could probably accomplish everything with jq filters from within yq, and based solely on your YAML input.

Comment: Updated the question with actual and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Why try to emulate jq's behavior with a shell loop ([which should generally be avoided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) instead of using jq directly?

```
yq -j "$file_name" | jq 'to_entries | map({
    Name: .key,
    Value: .value,
    Type: "String",
    Overwrite: true
})'
```

Or directly transform using [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/commands/evaluate) only:

```
yq 'to_entries | map({
    Name: .key,
    Value: .value,
    Type: "String",
    Overwrite: true
})' -j "$file_name"
```

---

Update after clarifying edit of the question: It has become clear that you want to transform the value into a string. jq has the `tostring` filter for that, the program thus becomes:

```
to_entries | map({
    Name: .key,
    Value: (.value | tostring),
    Type: "String",
    Overwrite: true
})
```

Note that this will not keep the line breaks and indents, but formats the JSON object in a "compact" way. Let us know if that's a problem.

```
$ jq 'to_entries | map({
    Name: .key,
    Value: (.value | tostring),
    Type: "String",
    Overwrite: true
})' <<JSON
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": {
    "id": "9ee ...",
    "parent": "abc..."
  }
}
JSON
[
  {
    "Name": "a",
    "Value": "1",
    "Type": "String",
    "Overwrite": true
  },
  {
    "Name": "b",
    "Value": "2",
    "Type": "String",
    "Overwrite": true
  },
  {
    "Name": "c",
    "Value": "{\"id\":\"9ee ...\",\"parent\":\"abc...\"}",
    "Type": "String",
    "Overwrite": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what's expected :

```
jq 'to_entries | map({
    Name: .key,
    Value: (.value|if (type == "object")
                   then tojson
                   else tostring
                   end),
    Type: "String",
    Overwrite: true})
' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

To JSON-encode data from within jq you can use the [`tojson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Convertto/fromJSON) (or [`@json`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping)) builtins.

Also, to get the actual type of some data, there is the [`type`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#type) function.

Maybe you are trying to accomplish something like this:

```bash
# Convert the the YAML file into JSON
json="$(yq -j "$file_name")"

# Transform the JSON data into desired format
jq 'to_entries | map({Name: .key} + (.value | {
      EncodedValue: tojson,
      OriginalType: type,
      Overwrite:    true
    }))' <<< "$json" > "$new_file_name"
```

Checking the contents of the new file would now give you something like:

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "a",
    "EncodedValue": "1",
    "OriginalType": "number",
    "Overwrite": true
  },
  {
    "Name": "b",
    "EncodedValue": "2",
    "OriginalType": "number",
    "Overwrite": true
  },
  {
    "Name": "c",
    "EncodedValue": "{\"id\":\"9ee ...\",\"parent\":\"abc...\"}",
    "OriginalType": "object",
    "Overwrite": true
  }
]
```